# Can't generate ruby exe using ocra due to ARGV[0]

Tags: ruby, command-line-arguments, ocra

Running the command `ocra script.rb --no-autoload --no-enc --add-all-core` gives me the error `initialize: can't convert nil into String (TypeError)` for the following line:

`doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.open(ARGV[0]))`

Whats going on here? I want to build the executable to be able to take any argument and use that file as the xml configuration.

Comment: why not use a CLI parser of some sort like [`slop`](https://github.com/leejarvis/slop) rather than just using `ARGV` this will also add to the readability of the code and may not suffer from the same compilation issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this above that line:

```
exit if defined? Ocra
# skip anything below this line when we're building the exe
```

Unless there's a `require` or otherwise loaded dependency below that line you should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

It seems a long time but the accept solution doesn't work for me.

The working solution is adding `--` then any fake data to your argument to make the execution flow to be just as normal

example for:

so you need to do

```
ocra yourscript.rb -- ANYDATAHERE
```